# Getting undesired result by using while loop to find the sum of n natural numbers

Tags: c, while-loop

I am attaching the code for the same.Its working fine.But once i enter a number less than the previous one it stops giving desired output.Any help/suggestion shall be greatly appreciated.

```
int i=1;
int j=0;
int n;
char ch;
while(ch!='n')
{
   printf("Enter the number upto which you want the sum of \n \n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   while(i<=n)
   {

      j=j+i;
      i++;

   } 
   printf("%d \n",j);
   printf("Do it with another number? Y/N \n \n");
   scanf("%s",&ch);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: You are getting your undesired result because of using an incorrect format specifier in `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&ch)` - that's a bad idea.

Comment: Also you are not re-initializing `j` and `i`.

Answer (score 2):

In your outer `while` loop, you're never resetting the value of the variable `i` back to `1`, or `j` back to `0`. That is why subsequent loops will produce an incorrect sum.

Comment: Thanks.That was quick.Am new.so this was really helpful.So now i am declaring the i,j,n variable inside the while loop.and its working.Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There are a smattering of bugs in this code, including:

1. Comparison to uninitialized value of  of `ch` in the initial `while` expression.
2. Failing to reset `i` and `j` for each outer-loop iteration
3. Failing to test for data-read success in either `scanf` call to ensure proper input.
4. The continuation `scanf("%s", &ch)` is simply wrong for a single character with skipped whitespace (which you must do to avoid reading the newline after your list integer input). Unless EOF or an error state is reached, what you have now is *guaranteed* to invoke undefined behavior, as a string-read of at least one character requires at least *two* for storage (the character, and a subsequent terminator).

Addressing all of those:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        int n;
        printf("Enter the number upto which you want the sum of \n \n");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) // See (3)
            break;

        int j = 0; // See (2)
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) // See (2)
            j += i;
        printf("%d \n", j);

        printf("Do it with another number? Y/N \n \n");
        if (scanf(" %c", &ch) != 1) // See (3) and (4)
            break;

    } while (ch != 'n' && ch != 'N'); // See (1)

    return 0;
}
```

Everything here is self-explanatory when referred to the previous bug punch list, save for maybe the format string for reading the single character. You mentioned in comments that you tried `%c` but it skipped to another loop iteration. That's because you didn't have the leading whitespace `" %c"` that tells `scanf` to skip white space before extracting the next argument. With that, it should work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `i` and `j` for every `n`.

```
i = 1;j=0;
while(i<=n)
{
```

Also your format specifer is wrong. For `char`, it should be `%c` and not `%s`

```
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

Comment: I tried with %c for character.but every time i use c as the format specifier the program automatically jumps to"enter the new value again" without taking the "yes/no" input.

Comment: @Learner94 That's because `"%c"` will read the next character in the input stream, which is going to be the newline following your last integer input. The `%c` specifier for `scanf` is unique in that regard; all the other format specifiers skip leading white space. You can instruct `scanf` to do that for characters as well by  putting a leading space before the `%c` in the format string, like this: `" %c"`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to set `i` to 0 at the outer `while`:

```
int i=1;
int j=0;
int n;
char ch;
while(ch!='n')
{
i = 0;
printf("Enter the number upto which you want the sum of \n \n");
scanf("%d",&n);

while(i<n)
{

j=j+i;
i++;

} 
printf("%d \n",j);
printf("Do it with another number? Y/N \n \n");
scanf("%s",&ch);
}
return 0;
```

Note that I have changed `<=` to `<` for your inner while, since you do not want to increment the value if the same `n` is inputted one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int n;
char ch;
while(ch!='n')
{
   printf("Enter the number upto which you want the sum of \n \n");
   scanf("%d",&n);
int i=1;//it should be 1 in every loop of the number
int j=0;//the sum should also be initialized to zero to erase the previous value 
   while(i<=n)
   {

      j=j+i;
      i++;

   } 
   printf("%d \n",j);
   printf("Do it with another number? Y/N \n \n");
   scanf("%c",&ch);//this is a char not a string
}
return 0;
}
```

> Due to the i is not initializing to 1 when the loop is coming for the second time there it is not going inside the loop and printing the previous value .